# "Everyone" Dynamic Group not appearing for share in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, groups, share

I am using Sharepoint Online (Office365). There are some default dynamic groups - "Everyone" and "Everyone except External Users", however I can only see "Everyone except External Users" when setting a permissions to some object. My goal is to share a site (kind of a landing page) where all external users would have access while the subsites have different groups and external users.

[image: Share with Everyone]

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, that worked.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/Everyone-external-Share-permission-in-SharePoint-Online-per-note/td-p/165305

```
Set-SPOTenant -ShowEveryoneClaim $true
```

Now "Everyone" appeared in the search and works as expected.