# Sharepoint site share with everyone option missing

Tags: sharepoint-online

I created a site with SharePoint that I want to external users to join; However, when I type everyone in the name in only option that appears is "Everyone except external users" I want to include external users how can I do that?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to configure your tenant for it to available.

Already has been answered in this forum. Take a look at [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/241844/everyone-dynamic-group-not-appearing-for-share-in-sharepoint-online)

```
Set-SPOTenant -ShowEveryoneClaim $true
```

Comment: I am planning to use SharePoint to have a site with a list of all forms where clients can open the site and submit a form; however, it doesn't seem to be possible because they need to be invited before hand. Which Microsoft app would you recommend where I could do that allow anyone to access the site even if it requires live email account to access as long it doesn't need an invitation.

Comment: Which **Forms** are you referring to? Can you be specific on that? Are you collecting external user information like email address using any kind of Forms. I know you can use MS Forms to collect that and then use PowerAutomate (FLOW) to save that data to SharePoint list. However, I don't see any easy way to grant external users permission to a SharePoint Online site.

Comment: It's possible to do that using MS Graph (HTTP connection) as described [here](https://www.timlinenterprises.com/how-to-invite-external-users-using-microsoft-flow-and-microsoft-graph-api/#:~:text=To%20do%20so%2C%20navigate%20to,will%20see%20our%20required%20permission) and grant permission [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-grant?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). I've not done that myself, but you can try.

Comment: It's necessary to grant permission first to make the user access the site.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement, official article for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/access-management/grant-everyone-claim-to-external-users#new-option-to-govern-access-for-external-users